# How to spawn enemies in a certain range but not in-camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, spawn

so I'm making a 2D platformer and I would like to spawn enemies on the whole map but not in the camera range.
I have to mention I am using Cinemachine to follow the player.

This is my script for the spawner:

```
*public class MobSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Mob;
    float randX;
    Vector2 whereToSpawn;
    public float spawnRate = 2f;
    float nextSpawn = 0.0f;
    public GameObject Camera;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            randX = Random.Range(-36f, 62);
            whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, transform.position.y);
            Instantiate(Mob, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
    
}*
```

As you can see I'm taking 2 points and in between them I spawn enemies. As this range would basically be the entire map, the camera will always be in it.

I want enemies to NOT spawn inside the camera yet spawn outside of it. How can I manage to do this?

Comment: Maybe use a collider which encapsulates the camera view on a special collision matrix to check if the enemy spawn position collides with it?

Comment: You can test against the camera frustum using the GeometryUtility CalculateFrustumPlanes and TestPlanesAABB.  Or you can do a WorldToScreenPoint making sure that the x and y are not in the Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height).  You would put your spawn code inside of a while loop that first tests the random position, if ok it spawns, if not it loops again.

Comment: I'd find the angle that isn't apart of the viewing spectrum. Once you have a direction vector that is outside of the viewing spectrum, add some scalar for the length and spawn. That way you don't need to loop or continually attempt at finding a valid location. You'd just know it's valid. Starting point could be [`this`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.CalculateFrustumCorners.html) doc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the simplest solution would be to just calculate vector distance between the player position and spawning position. Since this is a 2d space and you are spawning them only on one axis it should be fine.

So you could do

```
float distanceAwayFromCameraView = 5;
    
    // you will need a method, reference or just get the object via tag
    var playerPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
    
    randX = Random.Range(-36f, 62);
    whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, transform.position.y);
    
    while ((Vector2.Distance(whereToSpawn, playerPos) < distanceAwayFromCameraView){
        randX = Random.Range(-36f, 62);
        whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, transform.position.y);
    }
    
    Instantiate...
```

I'm not at my pc to test this right now, please let me know if there's errors